# What makes me legendary?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was surprised to see me being awarded the *legendary* badge for I just checked at https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation that I had "earned at least 200 reputation on **143** days". What is counted differently?

Comment: I think it was your performance at Woodstock.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you have earned 200 points on 150 days, but due to user removals, the number of days that show at least 200 points has been reduced. I believe that the badge counter remembers each day you've gotten at least 200, whereas the reputation page only counts the number of days that you are currently showing at least 200.

Comment: The same opinion was expressed in an answer to the meta.SO post: [Epic badge received too early?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early)